# Optional argument effects return type

Tags: typescript

Below I am trying to have a function that takes an optional argument `B` and conditionally handle the return if be is passed in or not.

```
export type SingleArgFunc = (arg: any) => any
export type SingleArgFuncs = { [k: string]: SingleArgFunc }

type Bextender<A> = (a: any) => any
type Cextender<A> = any
type Dextender<A, B, C> = B
// type Dextender<A, B, C> = B extends ????? : null : boolean

function Example<A extends SingleArgFuncs, B extends Bextender<A>>(a: A, b?: B) {
    return function Inner<C extends Cextender<B>>(c: C): Dextender<A, B, C> {
        return {} as Dextender<A, B, C>
    }
} 

const returnIs = Example({}) // const returnIs: <C extends any>(c: C) => Bextender<{}>
const returnIs2 = Example({}, () => 'meow') // const returnIs2: <C extends any>(c: C) => () => string
```

This seems to work by checking the return type of B but the condition is making it an intersection for some reason `boolean | null`.

```
export type SingleArgFunc = (arg: any) => any
export type SingleArgFuncs = { [k: string]: SingleArgFunc }

type Bextender<A> = (a: any) => any
type Cextender<A> = any
type Dextender<A, B, C> = B extends SingleArgFunc ? ReturnType<B> extends Bextender<A> ? null : boolean : never

function Example<A extends SingleArgFuncs, B extends Bextender<A>>(a: A, b?: B) {
    return function Inner<C extends Cextender<B>>(c: C): Dextender<A, B, C> {
        return {} as Dextender<A, B, C>
    }
} 

const returnIs = Example({}) // const returnIs: <C extends any>(c: C) => boolean | null
const returnIs2 = Example({}, () => 'meow') // const returnIs2: <C extends any>(c: C) => boolean
```

How can I write a conditional return if `B` is defined or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works:

```
export type SingleArgFunc = (arg: any) => any
export type SingleArgFuncs = { [k: string]: SingleArgFunc }

type CallbackAvailable<CbExt, Cb, IfA, NotA> = Cb extends SingleArgFunc ? CbExt extends ReturnType<Cb> ? IfA : NotA : never

type Bextender<A> = (a: any) => any
type Cextender<A> = any
type Dextender<A, B, C> = CallbackAvailable<Bextender<A>, B, null, true>

function Example<A extends SingleArgFuncs, B extends Bextender<A>>(a: A, b?: B) {
    return function Inner<C extends Cextender<B>>(c: C): Dextender<A, B, C> {
        return {} as Dextender<A, B, C>
    }
} 

const returnIs = Example({}) // const returnIs: <C extends any>(c: C) => boolean | null
const returnIs2 = Example({}, () => 'meow') // const returnIs2: <C extends any>(c: C) => boolean
```